# join multiple column with one column in linq

Tags: c#, linq, join

I need to join four tables `Table1, Table2, Table3 & Table4` and require all the data from Table1 and matching records from Table 2, 3 & 4. This seems to be straightforward, but due to the `constraint` between tables, I am not able to get the right `query`.

`Table2` & `Table3` are basically the association tables and holds the associations between `Table1` & `Table4`. I am trying to get the result through a `LINQ` query.

```
from t1 in context.Table1

join t2 in context.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.RefId into t2Temp
from t2 in t2Temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

join t3 in context.Table3 on t1.Id equals t3.RefId into t3Temp
from t3 in t3Temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

join t4 in context.Table4
//here I want all the rows where t4.RefId equals to both t2.RefId & t3.RefId, so that I can get all the associations from table4
on ..... //this is where I got confused how to put the condition
into t4Temp
from t4 in t4Temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

There are no direct references between Table1 & Table4. I hope this will help you to understand the question. I would be happier to add more information if required.

Comment: From your short description I guess it's something like `from t4 in context.Table4 where t4.RefId == t2.RefId || t4.RefId == t3.RefId`.

Comment: So after the first join with T2, you have combinations of [T1, T2] where every T2 has a `T2.RefId ==T1.Id`. After the 2nd join with T3, you have combinations [T1, T2, T3] where `T1.Id == T2.RefIds == T3.RefIds`. If you want join this with all T4 that have a `T4.RefId equal to `T2.RefId AND T3.RefId`, wouldn't that be the same as joining on `T4.RefId == T1.Id`? After all: every RefId in your [T1, T2, T3] combination equals the T1.Id!

Comment: @Gret Arnold Yes exactly!

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Yes, but I don't have the Id from Table1 referenced in any column of Table4

Answer (score -1):

Just try: `on t4.RefId equals t2.RefId || t4.RefId equals t3.RefId`
Then select properties in t1 and t4

Comment: That's invalid syntax. Please test code before posting.